# Python Filter JSON array data

Tags: python, arrays, json

I am trying to extract the required info from a JSON response. Under computer_network_adapter_summary there are multiple adapters from some responses there are 5 and in some responses >12. I am only interested in **Ethernet (where name contains "Intel(R) Ethernet")** and **wifi (where name contains "Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless")**

Is there any way I can filter only the required two adapter's mac addresses instead of all adapters? Thanks in advance.

```
response ='{"message_response":{"compdetailssummary":{"computer_summary":{"computer_name":"ABC","primary_owner":"Windows User","domain_name":"WORKGROUP"},"computer_network_adapter_summary":[{"dhcp_status":"Enabled","adapter_name":"[00000001] Fortinet Virtual Ethernet Adapter (NDIS 6.30)","mac_address":"00:00:0F:00:00:01","dhcp_server":"-","ip_address":"-","gateway":"-"},{"dhcp_status":"Enabled","adapter_name":"[00000004] Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I219-LM","mac_address":"00:00:0F:00:00:01","dhcp_server":"-","ip_address":"-","gateway":"-"},{"dhcp_status":"Enabled","adapter_name":"[00000005] Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260","mac_address":"00:00:0F:00:00:01","dhcp_server":"1.1.9.1","ip_address":"1.2.9.3","gateway":"1.1.8.1"},{"dhcp_status":"Enabled","adapter_name":"[00000007] Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)","mac_address":"00:00:0F:00:00:01","dhcp_server":"-","ip_address":"-","gateway":"-"},{"dhcp_status":"Disabled","adapter_name":"[00000002] PPPoP WAN Adapter","mac_address":"-","dhcp_server":"--","ip_address":"--","gateway":"--"},{"dhcp_status":"Enabled","adapter_name":"[00000003] Fortinet SSL VPN Virtual Ethernet Adapter","mac_address":"00:00:0F:00:00:01","dhcp_server":"--","ip_address":"--","gateway":"--"}]}}}'
json_data = json.loads(response)

computername = json_data['message_response']['compdetailssummary']['computer_summary']['computer_name']
ethMacAdd = json_data['message_response']['compdetailssummary']['computer_network_adapter_summary']
wifiMacAdd = json_data['message_response']['compdetailssummary']['computer_network_adapter_summary']

for item in json_data['message_response']['compdetailssummary']['computer_network_adapter_summary']:
    if item["adapter_name"] = "Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless":
        print(json_data['message_response']['compdetailssummary']['computer_network_adapter_summary'][0]["adapter_name"])
```

Comment: Of course there is a way. What have you tried? As of now, your question reads like "Do this for me", and that is [off-topic](/help/on-topic) here. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [mre] asking a _specific_ question about your attempt

Comment: Dear @PranavHosangadi i am not asking do this for me. I searched about it was confused that's i posted. If there is any example available please share where I can understand the method i will do it myself. So far i tried and get computername tried ethernet mac but it's not working
``` 
for item in d['message_response']['compdetailssummary']['computer_network_adapter_summary']:
    if item["adapter_name"] = "Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless":
        print(d['message_response']['compdetailssummary']['computer_network_adapter_summary'][0]["adapter_name"])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```
data = {
    "message_response": {
        "compdetailssummary": {
            "computer_summary": {
                "computer_name": "ABC",
                "primary_owner": "Windows User",
                "domain_name": "WORKGROUP"
            },
            "computer_network_adapter_summary": [
                {
                    "dhcp_status": "Enabled",
                    "adapter_name": "[00000001] Fortinet Virtual Ethernet Adapter (NDIS 6.30)",
                    "mac_address": "00:00:0F:00:00:01",
                    "dhcp_server": "-",
                    "ip_address": "-",
                    "gateway": "-"
                },
                {
                    "dhcp_status": "Enabled",
                    "adapter_name": "[00000004] Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I219-LM",
                    "mac_address": "00:00:0F:00:00:01",
                    "dhcp_server": "-",
                    "ip_address": "-",
                    "gateway": "-"
                },
                {
                    "dhcp_status": "Enabled",
                    "adapter_name": "[00000005] Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260",
                    "mac_address": "00:00:0F:00:00:01",
                    "dhcp_server": "1.1.9.1",
                    "ip_address": "1.2.9.3",
                    "gateway": "1.1.8.1"
                },
                {
                    "dhcp_status": "Enabled",
                    "adapter_name": "[00000007] Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)",
                    "mac_address": "00:00:0F:00:00:01",
                    "dhcp_server": "-",
                    "ip_address": "-",
                    "gateway": "-"
                },
                {
                    "dhcp_status": "Disabled",
                    "adapter_name": "[00000002] PPPoP WAN Adapter",
                    "mac_address": "-",
                    "dhcp_server": "--",
                    "ip_address": "--",
                    "gateway": "--"
                },
                {
                    "dhcp_status": "Enabled",
                    "adapter_name": "[00000003] Fortinet SSL VPN Virtual Ethernet Adapter",
                    "mac_address": "00:00:0F:00:00:01",
                    "dhcp_server": "--",
                    "ip_address": "--",
                    "gateway": "--"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

interesting_adapters = [adapter for adapter in data['message_response']['compdetailssummary']['computer_network_adapter_summary'] if
                        'Intel(R) Ethernet' in adapter['adapter_name'] or 'Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless' in adapter[
                            'adapter_name']]

print(interesting_adapters)
print(len(interesting_adapters))
```

output

```
[{'dhcp_status': 'Enabled', 'adapter_name': '[00000004] Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I219-LM', 'mac_address': '00:00:0F:00:00:01', 'dhcp_server': '-', 'ip_address': '-', 'gateway': '-'}, {'dhcp_status': 'Enabled', 'adapter_name': '[00000005] Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260', 'mac_address': '00:00:0F:00:00:01', 'dhcp_server': '1.1.9.1', 'ip_address': '1.2.9.3', 'gateway': '1.1.8.1'}]
2
```

Comment: Dear @balderman Thank You so much. I really appreciate your support.